# hold onto something

Tags: phrases

> I don’t know if she’s just mad that they left her out of the
>   practical joke war or if she’s just trying to put on a brave face, but
>   for the first time since I’ve met her, I feel a connection with her,
>   so I **hold onto it**.

What does it stand for, the connection or the joke war?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the connection.  I think this sentence is far too long, I'd rewrite it as:

> I don’t know if she’s just mad that they left her out of the practical
>   joke war or if she’s just trying to put on a brave face.  But for the
>   first time since I’ve met her I feel a connection with her, so I hold
>   onto it.